# get_the_post_thumbnail_url fullsize dIt does not work

Tags: wordpress

The following function should call the full-size image, but it doesn't.

```html
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($next_id, 'fullsize'); ?>
```

How could it be forced?

It does not work in amp but it does in no amp.

Complete code that I am using.

```html
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {?> <?php if(is_amp_endpoint()) { ?>
   
       <amp-img class="amp-wp-enforced-sizes" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($nextID, 'full'); ?>" width="372" height="186" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($post->post_title); ?>" layout="responsive" >
       <noscript><img decoding="async" alt="AMP" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($next_id, 'full'); ?>"></noscript>
       </amp-img>
     
   <?php } else {?>
  <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($next->ID, 'fullsize'); ?>
   
   <?php }} ?>
```

Thank

Answer (score 1):

They keyword here is 'full' not 'fullsize'
Correct code is

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($next_id, 'full'); ?>
```

Reference
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/#source

Comment: Thank you. It does not work on amp.
I have updated the question.